# unable to update/delete cookie in google chrome c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I can't seem to update my cookie on google chrome using the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _RemoveFromCart(int id)
{
    var usr = CommonFunctions.GetLoggedUser();
    HttpCookie mycookie = Request.Cookies[Sitesettings.UsersCart + "" + usr.Id];            
    List<Addtocart> lst = new List<Addtocart>();
    if (mycookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mycookie.Value))
    {
        string jsn = AESEncryptDecrypt.DecryptAsString(mycookie.Value);
        lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Addtocart>>(jsn);
        var item = lst.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        if (item != null && item.id > 0)
        {
            lst.Remove(item);
        }
        string jsnEnc = lst != null && lst.Count > 0 ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst) : "";                
        mycookie.Value = lst != null && lst.Count > 0 ? AESEncryptDecrypt.EncryptAsString(jsnEnc) : "";
        mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Sitesettings.CookieExpires);
        Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
        List<ProductModel> myret = lst != null && lst.Count > 0 ? CommonFunctions.GetProductsInCart() : new List<ProductModel>();

        var retvalue = lst != null && lst.Count > 0 ? GetCartJson(myret, lst) : Json(new { success = false, itemcount = 0 });
        return retvalue as JsonResult;
    }
    return Json(new { success = false, itemcount = 0 });
}
```

The value in the cookie is always the same and not seem to be updated, while in debugging I can see clearly the new value.

On firefox, it is working perfectly

Comment: I suspect cookie value . Could you provide  example of cookie value  that you want to update?

Comment: this is the cookie value: eWuaNkYegLuZZ70Gl4MRr/4LwHR90QWlktkCUMpN4cjwbLWSFV7rJp+4d3SEQZgqNwOC0uuiTVtQA0flNZ2ck4nfcAVm2Cj3sqJs1h96Id4=

Comment: insure that "Script Debugging" option is set to "enabled", as in image: https://ibb.co/zx0g7wR

Comment: @khaledsaleh, what does that have to do with cookies management?

Comment: i was have issue with clearing cookies in chrome, but when enabled this mode it works well, i think it affects chrome settings on your machine, give it a try